# Random JSP compliation errors - NullPointerException

Tags: jsp, jboss, nullpointerexception, tiles

I've got seemingly random NullPointerExceptions in a Java EE application with JBoss 4.0.5.GA.  After deployment, loading certain pages will cause a 500 error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
```

The root cause is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3737)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2130)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1599)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2213)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1705)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2213)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1705)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2213)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1705)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2213)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1705)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2213)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2219)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:456)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3320)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:305)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor385.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:243)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:275)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:161)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
atg.servlet.pipeline.TailPipelineServlet.service(TailPipelineServlet.java:90)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.servlet.pipeline.DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.service(DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.java:202)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.servlet.http.CookieBufferServlet.service(CookieBufferServlet.java:97)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.userprofiling.ExpiredPasswordServlet.service(ExpiredPasswordServlet.java:356)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.servlet.pipeline.MimeTyperPipelineServlet.service(MimeTyperPipelineServlet.java:206)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.service(DropletEventServlet.java:565)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.servlet.sessionsaver.SessionSaverServlet.service(SessionSaverServlet.java:2442)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.commerce.order.CommerceCommandServlet.service(CommerceCommandServlet.java:128)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.commerce.promotion.PromotionServlet.service(PromotionServlet.java:191)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.userprofiling.AccessControlServlet.service(AccessControlServlet.java:602)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.userprofiling.PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:169)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.userprofiling.SessionEventTrigger.service(SessionEventTrigger.java:461)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.userprofiling.ProfileRequestServlet.service(ProfileRequestServlet.java:477)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.servlet.pipeline.DynamoPipelineServlet.service(DynamoPipelineServlet.java:469)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.service(PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.java:370)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.userprofiling.sso.PassportServlet.service(PassportServlet.java:561)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.servlet.security.ThreadUserBinderServlet.service(ThreadUserBinderServlet.java:91)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.passRequest(HeadPipelineServlet.java:1099)
atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.service(HeadPipelineServlet.java:781)
atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:231)
atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor412.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:243)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:275)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:217)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
com.quebecor.commerce.filter.OpenSessionFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionFilter.java:49)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor411.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:243)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:275)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:217)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor410.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:243)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:275)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:217)
```

- This does not happen on a repeatable basis.  Between nightlies, the error will sometimes disappear.
- Sometimes, simply restarting the server (without redeploy) will cause the error to go away.
- Between deployments, the page(s) on which the error occurs might change.
- This does not occur on a development machine, but it does occur in the nightly builds and the pre-production environment.  Because it does not occur in dev, I can't debug it directly...
- On our nightly and pre-prod deployments, the work and tmp folders are completely emptied at each deployment.

We're using JBoss 4.0.5.GA and Java 1.5.0_11.  We also use Tiles 2.0.6 and the ATG E-commerce framework 2007.1.  We have not upgraded, replaced or removed any of our project dependencies.

Interestingly, this is only occurring in a new part of our site where we have developed a new set of JSPs from scratch, based on a new, independent Tiles templates.  The existing sections of the site do not exhibit any of these errors.

I tried pre-compiling the JSP pages with JSPC (using the instructions here:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web%20Application%20Compilation).  All of the pages compile successfully.

I'm at a bit of a loss.  Has anybody seen this error before?  Any tips or ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigations, it seems  that the compilation issue was related to Tag getters/setters type mismatch on a certain tag from the tiles library.

After upgrade to tiles 2.0.7 the issue seems resolved.

The jasper compilation mecanism ( at least in that version of tomcat) use java.beans.Introspector. A type mismatch between getXXX and setXXX could mess up the introspection process.

The issue was solved by tiles dev team a couple of years ago, read more about it at  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TILES-276

Comment: Thank you!  A quick update of an ancient library to a slightly-less-ancient library does the trick.

Comment: Well written for first answer!